# Locality in Bell Experiments

Tags: quantum-mechanics, locality

I have a question about experiments that show a violation of Bell's inequalities.  It's said that these experiments disprove local realism.  However, immediately before the final measurement of the 2 particles, the wave function of the 2 particles overlaps in space, right?  If so, wouldn't we say these particles are "local" to one another?

I realize that, after measurement, the 2 wave functions that are contained near the measurement devices and no longer overlapping, but before?

I'd expect a reasonable definition of locality to include 2 particles with overlapping wave functions.  Right?  If not, when are 2 particles considered local to one another?

Comment: Bell's inequalities are violated when you perform measurements on *entangled* states of two subsystems (particles for example). Two such particles have no individual wave functions. Only the combined system has one. It also seems like you are mixing up superposition with entanglement.

Comment: My point is that the (mixed) state of each particle overlaps the other in space (before measurement), right?  So they are not "distant" until AFTER the Bell-violating measurement.  (I realize they are entangled and what that means.)

Comment: OK. What about [this experiment by Zeilinger et.al.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation#Quantum_teleportation_over_143_km)  where entangled photons were 143km apart ?

Comment: I'm speaking of the wavefunction *before* measurement.  After measurement/collapse it's distant, but the instant before I believe the spread is so large that they overlap.